How to track down the source of unknown device connection requests?
I have a ASUS ZenWifi ET8 router connected to a Starlink. I have set up MAC filtering (acceptance feature listing the only devices allowed on the WiFi).
I am still getting random device connected messages from the router for random MACs in the range of 00:02:00… and 00:03:00….
How can I track down the source of these intrusion attempts?
As a note, these MACs intrusions started after I installed a new DirecTV Genie C51-700 remote connected only to the DirecTV receiver's coax network. I have DirecTV blocked on the ASUS router side.

00:02:00 is Net & Sys Co., Ltd., 00:03:00 is Barracuda Networks, Inc.

Up until last week we never had these addresses attach to the network.  Interesting though is that each attempt is a slightly different address. Spoofed?
